# Stuck on 'Grass Roots' mission as Franklin

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm stuck on Franklin's 'Grass Roots' mission and can't quit. I can't do a different mission or even do anything at all on the mission I'm stuck on. I stole the truck and walked around near it but nothing happened even after I drove to the location I needed to get to, and the same thing happens with the tow truck and broken car.

I am playing on the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your actually driving over the waypoint it's set to, it's behind apartment blocks on the right side of the road, if you follow the waypoint

Comment: I am and I've done the YouTube tutorials on how to do the mission but I'm still stuck

Comment: Maybe the game is a little scratched or something? Try installing the game?